# Every collection of disjoint non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

This is my first question on the forum. I'm wondering if the following proof is valid.

---

**Proof:**
Let $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in L}$ be an arbitrary collection of disjoint non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Since every non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written uniquely as a countable union of disjoint open intervals, we can take the union $A = \bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in L}A_\lambda$ and decompose it $A = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n$ in disjoint open intervals which forms a countable collection. We can also decompose each $A_\lambda$ as $\bigcup\limits_{m \in \mathbb{N}}J_{\lambda,m}$. For $\lambda \neq \mu \in L$, $A_\lambda \cap A_\mu = \emptyset$ and this is a new representation of $A$:

$$A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n = \bigcup_{\substack{\lambda \in L \\ m \in \mathbb{N}}} J_{\lambda,m}$$

No matter how complicated the union over $L$ is, the $J_{\lambda,m}$ are disjoint open intervals. Thus, by the uniqueness, the two collections are exactly the same. As the final argument, we produce an injection $\varphi:\{A_\lambda\} \mapsto \{J_{\lambda,m}\}$ picking for each $A_\lambda$ some $J_{\lambda,m}$.

---

I can't see any fault, but the result seems incredibly strong to me.

P.S.: stack exchange has some bug related to \bigcup and \bigcap symbols?

Comment: For simpler argument, pick a rational in each open set. Since there are only countably many rationals, we are finished.  Comment: You seem to be using the symbol for intersection when you mean union.

Comment: Hi @ArturoMagidin, the bug i mentioned is related to the preview window. I wrote \bigcup and the preview showed me \bigcap at the first time. Maybe was my browser, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. There is no need to sign your messages because your user-name always appears to the right. If by "bug" you refer to the fact that the limits occur to the right of the symbol when doing in-line equations, that's how $\LaTeX$ always does it. If you want to get the limits "under" and "under" when doing an in-line equation, you need to use the `\limits` command. For example, `\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i` produces $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, but `\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i` will give you $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i$.

Comment: @juliohm: Hmmm... that sound weird. Could you have typed `\bigcap` instead by mistake?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: No, i've searched twice for typing errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To each of those open disjoint subsets you can associate one and only one rational number (just pick a rational number in the set). Thus you obtain an injection from your family of subsets **into** the set of rational numbers, which is countable. The conclusion follows that your family must indeed be countable.

Comment: That is true! And the same argument is used when showing the structure of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. So much simple. Thank you @Weltschmerz.

Comment: @juliohm Sure. Could you try to find conditions under which the statement is true for non-disjoint families?

Comment: Do you have such a generalization? Would be great to discuss about it. How could i proceed to achieve a similar result with non-disjoint families?

Comment: @juliohm Start with small families. See what happens with the intersections.

Comment: Ok @Weltschmerz, i'll think better.

Comment: Here, it is more clear that where Axiom of Choice has been applied !

Comment: @Fardad I did use the Axiom of Choice. Namely, when I say, pick a rational number from each set.

Comment: yes yes i knew. thanks. I meant in your way, what you just said, is clear

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that:

> "...every non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written uniquely as a countable union of disjoint open intervals..."

is *essentially* what you are trying to prove (in fact, it's *stronger* than what you are trying to prove; it includes a *uniqueness* clause). So I would be very wary of using it.

In addition, any argument that argues by saying "No matter how complicated the union..." is likely to be at least a little bit informal.

The result you are trying to prove can be established without invoking that rather strong result.

Here's a hint: since the rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, if $A$ is any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $A\cap\mathbb{Q}\neq\emptyset$. Can you see why this observation yields the desired result?

Comment: I see, thank you Arturo. This forum is amazing. I'll try to avoid the "No matter..." phrase next time.

Answer (score 6):

Your argument seems valid to me, though I think that in assuming that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a unique representation as a countable disjoint union of open intervals, you're swatting a fly with a sledgehammer.

How about this?  In a disjoint collection $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of nonempty open subsets, choose a rational number $x_{i}$ in each $U_i$.  then you get an injection $I \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, so $I$ is countable.  (Really this argument works in any **separable** topological space, i.e., whenever you have a countable dense subset.)