# Set of intervals on the real line

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure how to approach this proof? any ideas
Let $A$ be a set of intervals of the real line any two of which are disjoint - in other words, if $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$ are distinct elements of $A$ then $(a,b)\cap(x,y)=\emptyset$. Prove that A is countable. *(Use the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is countable)

Comment: How many intervals in $A$ can contain the given rational number?

Comment: Hint: You can assign to each $(a,b) \in A$ an element $q_{(a,b)} \in (a,b) \cap \mathbb Q$. This gives a map $f:A \to \mathbb Q$. What can you say about $f$?

Comment: @martini the function f is surjective? i still don't understand what you mean by q(a,b)∈(a,b)∩Q. Thanks

Comment: No, $f$ is never surjective. By $q_{(a,b)} \in (a,b) \cap \mathbb Q$ I mean the following: $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a non-empty intervall, so there is a rational number $q_{(a,b)}$ with $a < q_{(a,b)} < b$, i. e. it is contained in the intersection of $(a,b)$ with $\mathbb Q$, so $q_{(a,b)} \in (a,b) \cap \mathbb Q$ (if the index to $q$ is confusing you, for different intervalls there will be different rational numbers [as your intervalls are disjoint]. $f$ is now defined by $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr) := q_{(a,b)}$.

Comment: List the rationals as $r_1,r_2,\dots$. For any of our intervals $(a,b)$, let $f((a,b))$ be the least integer $i$ such that $r_i$ is in $(a,b)$.

Comment: @martini Thanks for clearing that up. Therefore f is injective function?

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks

Comment: Yes. And now, since there is an injective $f\colon A \to \mathbb Q$ and the fact you gave in your question ...

Comment: @martini A is countable? thanks allot.

Comment: @Jenn Yes, $A$ is countable.

Comment: A similar question: [Every collection of disjoint non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb R$ is countable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75781/every-collection-of-disjoint-non-empty-open-subsets-of-mathbbr-is-countable).

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ each interval contains some positive number of rational numbers. For each interval $I_{k}$ choose such a rational number $a_k \in I_k$, and denote the set of all such $a_k$ as $N$. This set is clearly countable, as it is a subset of the rational numbers, and thus $N$ is of an equal or smaller cardinality. Note that $N$ is one to one with $A$, and thus has equal size. $A$ is therefore countable.

Comment: What does this answer add to what's already in the comments on the question?

Comment: Nitpicking: "some number" should be "some positive number"