# Is it possible to find an uncountable number of disjoint open intervals in $R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it possible to find an uncountable number of disjoint open intervals in $R$?

Several times I saw the sentence

> every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a countable number of open intervals (Because $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable)

Suppose we are able to find an uncountable number of disjoint open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, then union of these intervals is an open set (say $G$) in $\mathbb{R}$. But $G$ cannot be expressed as a countable number of open intervals.

Thus my answer is there is no such a collection exist.
Is my think is correct? Give more hints and clarify it..!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789690/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75781/

Answer (score 20):

No, in a disjoint union of open intervals $(I_j)_{j\in J}$ each interval  $I_j$ contains a rational number $q_j$ which enables to define an injection $J\rightarrow Q$ which sends $j$ to $q_j$.

Comment: Ohh... there is a 1-1 correspondence from set of intervals to a subset of rational number.

Comment: And subset of a countable set is countable. Thus we can't find a uncountable disjoint open intervals in R. Thank you...!!

Comment: Is this function well defined? What criteria are we using to pick the rational?

Comment: @Akash - You can pick *any* rational in each interval $I_j$. If the amount of intervals, $|J|$ was uncountable then since each interval $I_j$ contains at least one rational number, certainly the set of rationals would be uncountable which is not true.