# There is no uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open sets in $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Working in $R_{\text usual}$ Topology:
Show that there is no uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Definition of $R_{\text usual}$ I'm working with:
$\{U \subseteq \mathbb R: \forall x \in U \exists \ \epsilon \  s.t (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subseteq U \}$
We are looking for an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb R$,

1.Since rationals are a countable subset of $\mathbb R$, and

2.Every open set in $R_{\text usual}$ also contains rationals (choose an interval of width $2\epsilon$ around x, choose integer n larger that $\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$, choose integer a s.t $\frac{a}{n} \leq (x - \epsilon$) then $\frac{a + 1}{n} \in (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ by definition of n. )

Then by 1 and 2 there can not exist an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathbb R$

Am I in the right direction ?

Comment: You forgot "open" in your title.

Comment: @jia So if each open set in this uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ contains a rational number, how many rational numbers would that be altogether? Do you even need to worry about $\epsilon$?

Comment: You mean "I'm working with: $\{U\subseteq \Bbb R : ...\}$ (inclusion not membership).

Comment: Thank you Brian, I edited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the proof. Why are you asking?! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the direction to look at is to consider that any open set in $\mathbb R$ contains an interval. So: does exists an uncountable collection of disjoint intervals? (But the rational number are countable...)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an uncountable collection of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you can choose a rational out of each of these intervals.  By disjointness, this map is 1-1. We have an injective map of an uncountable set into a countable one. OOPS. Contradiction.  By reductio ad absurdum, such a collection cannot exist.